# Playonlinux install menu stuck

Tags: playonlinux

My playonlinux starts just fine. I type in playonlinux on the Terminal Command Center and it shows up. When I click install, the playonlinux menu gets stuck on this reloading logo. 
[image: screen-shot]

Answer (score 1):

That's a symptom of the PlayOnLinux app not being able to connect to the Playonlinux server.  It's trying to update the list.

At the time of your question, I tried the PlayOnLinux install feature on 5 computers and got the same.  The "Updating List" never appeared.

Now it works on all the computers.  Running it from the console I could see that it never made it to the "Updating List" console message.

To test the theory, I disabled the network on one of the computers.  That caused the issue.

Since all my computers had an internet connection at the time of the posting of your question, and none of them worked.  It appears that the problem was due to the actual problems with PlayOnLinux server, in that case, of which it was temporarily down for everybody.

**Quick Answer (tested)**

The PlayOnLinux app can't connect to the PlayOnLinux server to update the Install Listing.